# Keeping word in the second position when the first position is an answer to a question separated by a comma?

Tags: grammaticality

*- Hat er gute Laune oder schlechte Laune?
- Eher schlechte Laune, denke Ich*

is the position of "denke" correct here? Does a comma imply a differrent clause here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title to this question is rather confusing but I'll simply answer the two questions you formulated.
Yes, the position of "denke" is correct. The word "ich" is not written with capital "i" though.

The answer is basically a shortened form of:
*"Er hat eher schlechte Laune, denke ich."* In order to seperate the clauses you use a comma. The comma is also necessary if you switch the clauses: "Ich denke, er hat eher schlechte Laune."

Comment: Thanks, "ich" being capital was a typo. Is the reason for the inverted verb order in "Denke ich" because it is the second clause? I recall a rule that the word order is inverted in a sentence with 2 independent clauses in the clause that comes second. But now I realize, that if this is the case then it would have been "Ich denke, hat er eher schlechte Laune" which is probably wrong.

Comment: Yes, that would be wrong. If I have time, I'll write another edit for that...

Comment: I'm looking forward to it. I seemed to have a subconscious notion that if there is a comma involved it must be because it is separating clauses. But in this case, the word order is reversed because "Eher schlechte Laune" is part of the main clause and the verb is trying to stay in the second position, right?

Comment: Alright, here we go: The rule to memorize is that the finite verb is in second position. And here, the dependent clause would be in the first position. So it is either "Eher schlechte Laune [position 1], denke [position 2] ich [position 3]." or "Ich [position 1] denke [position 2], eher schlechte Laune [position 3]."

Comment: So, if the dependent clause is in the second position, that will force the verb in the main clause to go to the first position right?

But you mentioned that this is the shortened version of _Er hat eher schlechte Laune, denke ich_.

But this sentence seems to be made of 2 independent clauses, then why is the word order reversed?

Would _Ich denke, hat er eher schlechte Laune._ would be wrong as you pointed out. But why can't we reverse the word order here in the second clause?

Comment: I would have to guess that this is due to the fact that we are dealing with indirect speech here.

Comment: So, in short, indirect speech occupying first position means that verb will have to be in the second one right? 
Then I guess it doesn't have much to do with it being a short for of _Er hat eher schlechte Laune_ since this would create 2 separate independent clauses

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Nevertheless, what I stated above stays true for other cases